# Making a single table from multiple files

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I want to merge multiple two column tab-delimited files in the format:

```
  a
A 5
C 4  
D 2

  b
A 2
B 5
C 3

  c
B 4
C 4
D 2
```

Into a single table in this format:

```
  a b c
A 5 2 0
B 0 5 4
C 4 3 4
D 2 0 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You essentially want to create a two-dimensional array of values. The first column on each row corresponds to a *key*, taken from the first tab-delimited field on each line in each input file. Each following column corresponds to a separate input file.

```
awk 'BEGIN {
         RS = "(\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n)"
         FS = " *\t *"
         SUBSEP = ":"
     }
     FNR==1 {
         ++file
     }
     NF>=2 {
         if ($1 in keynum)
             key = keynum[$1]
         else {
             key = ++keys
             keynum[$1] = key
             keystr[key] = $1
         }
         value[key,file] = $2
     }
     END {
         files = file
         for (key = 1; key <= keys; key++) {
             printf "%s", keystr[key]
             for (file = 1; file <= files; file++)
                 printf "\t%s", value[key,file]
             printf "\n"
         }
     }' INPUT1 INPUT2 ... INPUTN
```

The `BEGIN` rule sets the record separator to any type of newline, so that each line is a separate record. It also sets the field separator to a tab, including any spaces around it.

In awk, all arrays are associative, and basically one-dimensional. Multidimensional arrays are supported by concatenating the indexes, with a `SUBSEP` in between. Here, we use `:` as a separator, because the indexes used are positive integers. (You could use lots of other characters if you wanted to; like a tab `\t`, for example.)

The `FNR==1` rule is triggered on the first line of each input file. We increment the variable `file`, so that it is `1` for the first input file, `2` for the second, and so on.

The `NF>=2` rule is triggered for all records with at least two fields. In this case, it means for each line that has a tab character. The first field is the *key*, and the second field the *value*.

The variable `key` is a positive integer, referring to an unique key string. (1 refers to the first unique *key* seen, 2 to the second, and so on, across all input files.)

The `keynum` associative array maps key strings to key numbers (`key`, positive integers). The `keystr` is the inverse mapping, mapping key numbers to key strings.

In the `NF>=2` rule, if the first field is already a known key, its number is looked up. Otherwise, the first field is added as a new unique key string. Then, the second field is saved to the `value` array.

The `END` rule is triggered after all input files have been processed. The `value` array, a logically two-dimensional array, contains the fields we want.

The outer loop loops `key` over all unique keys seen, in the order they were first seen. Each iteration of the outer loop produces one output line.

The inner loop loops `file` over each input file, in the order they were listed. Each iteration produces an additional column to the current line output. Each output line contains exactly one more columns than the number of input files specified. (Note that if no input files are specified, awk reads from standard input, and that's counted as if it was one input file.)

This is definitely not the simplest method to achieve this, but I like this, because it is robust (accepts input files created in Unix, Linux, old Macs, new Macs, Windows -- basically anywhere that uses an ASCII-compatible character set; also, it won't get confused if some input files have only a subset of all of the known keys), relatively easy to understand, maintain, and adapt to similar cases.

---

If you want to run the above as a script, save the following as e.g. `paste.awk`:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
    RS = "(\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n)"
    FS = " *\t *"
    SUBSEP = ":"
}
FNR==1 {
    ++file
}
NF>=2 {
    if ($1 in keynum)
        key = keynum[$1]
    else {
        key = ++keys
        keynum[$1] = key
        keystr[key] = $1
    }
    printf "key = %s, file = %s, value = %s\n", key, file, $2 >/dev/stderr
    value[key,file] = $2
}
END {
    files = file
    for (key = 1; key <= keys; key++) {
        printf "%s", keystr[key]
        for (file = 1; file <= files; file++)
            printf "\t%s", value[key,file]
        printf "\n"
    }
}
```

If you have `input1` containing

```
        a
A       5
C       4
D       2
```

and `input2` containing

```
        b
A       2
B       5
C       3
```

and `input3` containing

```
        c
B       4
C       4
D       2
```

but with the second character on each line being <kbd>Tab</kbd>; i.e. created using e.g.

```
printf ' \ta\nA\t5\nC\t4\nD\t2\n' > input1
printf ' \tb\nA\t2\nB\t5\nC\t3\n' > input2
printf ' \tc\nB\t4\nC\t4\nD\t2\n' > input3
```

or, if you copy and paste the text above into files, run `sed -e 's|^\(.\)  *|\1\t|' -i input1 input2 input3` to fix them; then, running

```
paste.awk input1 input2 input3
```

outputs

```
        a       b       c
A       5       2       
C       4       3       4
D       2               2
B               5       4
```

except that the consecutive spaces above are actually <kbd>tab</kbd>s. The software on this site converts tabs to spaces, you see.

Edited to add: If you want to use some predefined value for missing entries, modify the `END` rule into

```
END {
    files = file
    for (key = 1; key <= keys; key++) {
        printf "%s", keystr[key]
        for (file = 1; file <= files; file++)
            if ((key SUBSEP file) in value)
                printf "\t%s", value[key,file]
            else
                printf "\t%s", blank
        printf "\n"
    }
}
```

and set the variable `blank` to reflect the value you want. (You can either set it from the command line, using `./paste.awk -v blank=0 input1 input2 input3`, or modify the awk code and set the value somewhere in the `BEGIN` rule or the beginning of the `END` rule.)

Comment: I'm getting back "^ syntax error". I'm running `awk program.awk file1 file2 file3 > output_file` where program.awk is the code between the single quotes.

Comment: You need to run `awk -f program.awk file1 file2 file3 > output_file`. To specify a script for awk to run, you *need* to use the `-f` option. Note that I extended my answer to show an explicit way where you can run either `awk -f paste.awk file1 file2 file3` or (if you have run e.g. `chmod a+x paste.awk` to give execute permissions on the file) `./paste.awk file1 file2 file3`, as well as the output based on the example inputs.

Answer (score 3):

`join` is the tool to use, but its options get a bit nasty:

```
join -t $'\t' -a1 -a2 -o 0,1.2,2.2     file1 file2 |
join -t $'\t' -a1 -a2 -o 0,1.2,1.3,2.2     - file3 |
sed 's/\t\(\t\|$\)/\t0\1/g'
```

```
    a   b   c
A   5   2   0
B   0   5   4
C   4   3   4
D   2   0   2
```

I first used the `-e` option, but that caused problems with the header row.

Comment: I was about to suggest `join -t $'\t' -a1 -a2 -e0 -o0,1.2,2.2,2.3 <(sed '1 s/^/@\t/' file1) <(join -t $'\t' -a1 -a2 -e0 -o0,1.2,2.2 <(sed '1 s/^/@\t/' file2) <(sed '1 s/^/@\t/' file3))` which seems to keep `-e` happy by adding a lexically appropriate key for the header rows.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a GNU awk version. First I find all the key values, so I can fill in empty values with zero:

```
keys=$(cut -d $'\t' -f1 file{1,2,3} | sort -u | paste -sd,)
gawk -F'\t' -v keys="$keys" '
    BEGIN {
        n = split(keys,k,/,/)
        for (i=1; i<=n; i++) values[k[i]] = k[i]
    }
    {v[$1] = $2} 
    ENDFILE {
        for (key in values) 
            values[key] = values[key] FS (v[key] ? v[key] : 0)
        delete v
    } 
    END {
        for (key in values) print values[key]
    }
' file1 file2 file3 | sort -t $'\t' -k 1,1
```